# Count the number of occurrences in a string array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm experimenting with Java arrays. What I want to do is count the occurrences of an array string element. For example:

```
Clubs - 8 
Clubs - Ace 
Clubs - Jack
Hearts - 9 
Spades - 3
Hearts - 6
```

**Number of occurrences:**

```
Clubs - 3
Hearts - 2
Spades - 1
Diamonds - 0
```

So far I only have coded this:

```
public class CardGame {
public static void main(String[] args){

     String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades" };
     String[] deck = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                        "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Aces" };

     for( int a = 0; a < 7; a++ ){
     int i = (int) ( Math.random() * suit.length );
     int j = (int) ( Math.random() * deck.length );
         //System.out.println( "Suit " + suit[i] + " Deck " + deck[j] );
     System.out.println( suit[(int) (Math.random() * suit.length)]
             + " : " + deck[(int) (Math.random() * deck.length)]);
     }
            System.out.println();

  }
}
```

Give me some ideas on how to accomplish this. Thanks.

**NOTE:** This is not a homework. I'm just trying to give myself some exercises regarding arrays.

Comment: Is there a Limit regarding the number of different words?

Comment: You haven't coded anything regarding finding count??

Comment: @gefei the homework tag is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: You should check out the Java tutorials I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have missunderstood the answer to your previous question. The idea is to use the values of i and j in the cycle, not to generate them twice. Here is a working example. I am not using hash map because you know the suits and their count aforehand so just an array is enough:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){

         String[] suit = { "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades" };
         String[] deck = { "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10",
                            "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Aces" };
         int counts[] = new int[4];
         for( int a = 0; a < 7; a++ ){
         int i = (int) ( Math.random() * suit.length );
         int j = (int) ( Math.random() * deck.length );
             //System.out.println( "Suit " + suit[i] + " Deck " + deck[j] );
         System.out.println( suit[i] + " : " + deck[j]);
         counts[i]++;
         }
                System.out.println();
         for (int i =0;i<4;++i){
            System.out.println(suit[i] + " : " + counts[i]);
         }

      }
    }
```

You can see the code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/8q4s6).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) to save the number of occurences.

```
Map<String, Integer> occurences = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for(String value : array)
{
    Integer oldValue = occurences.get(value);
    if(oldValue == null)
        occurences.put(value, 1);
    else
        occurences.put(value, oldValue + 1);
}
```

However, you may want to get rid of the numbers at the end first (hint: use [`String#split("-")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and [`String#trim()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) afterwards).

Comment: +1 If you do the `get()` first you can avoid using `containsKey`. I would also use Map as the variable type.

Comment: @PeterLawrey You are right. Changed it.

Answer (score 2):

You can maintain counters in

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1):

For you interest two variations on using `Map<String, Integer>`

```
final Map<String, AtomicInteger> countMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

public void count(String text) {
    AtomicInteger ai = countMap.get(text);
    if (ai == null) countMap.put(text, ai = new AtomicInteger());
    ai.getAndIncrement();
}
```

or

```
TObjectIntHashMap<String> countMap = new TObjectIntHashMap<>();

public void count(String text) {
    countMap.adjustOrPutValue(text, 1, 1);
}
```

The [TObjectIntHashMap](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/map/hash/TObjectIntHashMap.html) can be more efficient as it can reduce the number of objects created.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation of your problem (running with JRE 6):

```
package test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Clubs - 8");
        list.add("Clubs - Ace");
        list.add("Clubs - Jack");
        list.add("Hearts - 9");
        list.add("Spades - 3");
        list.add("Hearts - 6");

        Map<String, Integer> countMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (String card : list) {
            String suit = card.split("-")[0].trim();
            String deck = card.split("-")[0].trim();
            if (countMap.containsKey(suit)) {
                countMap.put(suit, countMap.get(suit) + 1);
            } else {
                countMap.put(suit, 0);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Count of cards:");
        for (String card : countMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(card + ":" + countMap.get(card));
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Count of cards:
Spades:0
Hearts:1
Clubs:2
```

Comment: Instead of deck I suspect you want `String rank = card.split("-")[1].trim();` although you don't need it in this case.

Comment: Which is better for me to use hashmap or array? Is there a performance factor in using hashmap?

Comment: Order of retrival in a hashmap is usually O(1) so its obviously better

Answer (score 0):

do this:

```
int[] suitCount=new int[4];
for( int a = 0; a < 7; a++ ){
 int i = (int) ( Math.random() * suit.length );
 int j = (int) ( Math.random() * deck.length );
     //System.out.println( "Suit " + suit[i] + " Deck " + deck[j] );
 System.out.println( suit[(int) (Math.random() * suit.length)]
         + " : " + deck[(int) (Math.random() * deck.length)]);
suitCount[i]++;
 }
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
System.out.println(suit[i]+" - "+suitCount[i]);
```

Though, I am not sure how you expect the println method to print when you are reassigning the indices of the suit and deck, insted, replace them with i and j respectively.

}